# Building Responsive UI in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, responsive-design

I'm new to android and android studio.

I'm working on a project that should be optimized for all screens.

My app runs in portrait mode so I have locked Landscape Orientation both before running and in running status.

Now I'm in deadend. I want to know that which item is impotant in design?

In an article I have read that I should have 4 layouts (small, normal, large and xlarge) for my activities, but when I lunch my app in android studio emulator with 5.0" screen size it run successfully, But when I run it on real device with 5.0" screen my layout not shown fully in screen.

In another article I have read that for responsive design I should use all densities(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and etc)

now I confused how to prevent hard coding for location and size of items in android designing.

please help me it is so neccessary for me to lear this issue

Comment: 99% of the time you only need 1 layout for a screen, possibly with a few values in different values based on screen size.  But it all depends on what you're doing.  THis question is far too broad to answer effectively.

Comment: Hello, i recommend you read this https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes the best way is to create your folders for each density and screen size, to avoid the excess of 64k (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=ES#avoid) methods in your project and avoid having more libraries than you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library https://github.com/intuit/sdp to build a responsive layout optimized for all screens.

It actually presents a new scale unit called `sdp` (scalable dp).

Here is an example of how to use it after adding the dependency to your build.gradle file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_27sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_50sdp" >

     <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Intuit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this example as you can see that I use sdp instead of dp.

You can try it and you will see that even the textSize will resize depending on your screen and keep the same textSize/resolution ratio.

Comment: I added an example and explained it.